# How do I get the stored procedure result set into temp table without creating temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I get the stored procedure result set into temp table without creating temp Table.

Also I did not use Openrowset command.Please help.I want like this

```
insert * into #tab
exec Tet1.dbo.Proc_GeSpecific @dataToPass
```

Comment: As a matter of good practice, you **should** always strongly type your temporary tables through a `CREATE TABLE #tempTable` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax to use in order to insert result of a stored procedure into a temp table:

```
INSERT #table(column1, column2,...)
EXEC Tet1.dbo.Proc_GeSpecific @dataToPass
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is not a solution, he is asking if it is possible to do it without creating the table before

Comment: The proposed solution is inserting the result of the stored procedure into a temporary table. The temporary table isn't created before the stored procedure execution. The alternative with table creation would be starting with `CREATE TABLE #table ...`